# JQuery arrow function substitute

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, arrow-functions

I'm making a Cordova/Phonegap app with Jquery.

This set of code works on my localhost site when debugging - but not when running the app on my phone.

`${_priWaardes[i].children.map(child => "<li>" + child + "</li>")}`

Apparently - this is because of the fact that Cordova webview does not yet support arrow functions.

What are the alternatives to displaying the child of an array as such ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `child => "<li>" + child + "</li>"` is almost equivalent to `function (child) { return "<li>" + child + "</li>";}`

Comment: Use the functions that have been around since the 1990s, and are therefore very well documented, and easy to find information about.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is the original `function` which is practically equivalent to arrow functions.

```js
${_priWaardes[i].children.map(function(child) {
   return "<li>" + child + "</li>"
})}
```

The arrow function was introduced in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) and is not supported on all platforms. To avoid issues it may be a good idea to use the old syntax or something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/).